# How to get a list of possible predicate values

Tags: prolog

Lets I have a predicate `p/1` defined, for example, as follows:

```
p(2).
p(3).
p(5).
p(7).
```

How can I define a predicate `p_list/1` which will be true for a list of all possible values of `p/1` (in above case - `[2, 3, 5, 7]`) in the backtracking order?

Simple enumeration of the values is not acceptable because it makes maintenance more difficult. Moreover values, can be defined implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[maplist](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)/2 works well for check, while [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 it's the basic list constructor in Prolog

Try

```
?- findall(X, p(X), L), maplist(p, L).
```

Comment: Is there `maplist` call really needed? `findall` seems working well itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bagof(X, p(X), L)` which gives you L = [2,3,5,7].
What do you mean by "defined implicitly" ? Can you give an example.

Comment: In the simplest case there can be an explicitly enumerated predicate `edge/2` means the edge of a graph, and predicate `vertex/1` means anything occurs in edges. `vertex`'s values can be changed without changing definition of the predicate itself.